# Polish char is getting changed to a differerent char when loading into Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, character-encoding, oracle11g, informatica

I'm loading a file into oracle DB 11g via informatica 9.

The source file contains a polish char in a column given below:

```
US1_GPBAS - GPRS - dostęp do publicznych APN
```

When loading into DB, it gets converted to following data:

```
US1_GPBAS - GPRS - dostÄ™p do publicznych APN
```

The file encoding of source file is UTF-8.
In the DB NLS_CHARACTERSET is AL32UTF8

What could be the issue here.

Comment: It looks like the bytes are *saved* correctly, but being *displayed* by interpreting them as if they were Windows-1252. Where are you reading the database contents? In a webpage?

Comment: i am using database SQL developer for reading DB. n for source file, notepad++ is being used.

Answer (score 0):

You need t check the encoding of the relational connection you are using to load the data from Informatica.
Try setting that to UTF-8 as well, that solved it for me once.

Answer (score 0):

Code page has to be synced throughout all the channels.

In your case source target and repository code page should be same in order to read data(Source code page)...Transform data(repository code page)... Load Data(Target code page).

You might not get any error but data is translated into different code page if any of the above three are out of sync.